# Htaccess - Remove all trailing slashes except for directories and subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following code in the `.htaccess` file to remove trailing slashes from URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd like to add an exception to this rule. I'd like to keep the slashes for directories and subdirectories. My knowledge of Apache is quite limited so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to write folders for which the slashes will keeped.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myfolder/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myfolder1/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myfolder2/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you can write folders for which the rules will ignored:

```
RewriteRule ^(folder|folder1|folder2|folder3)($|/) - [L]
```

WARNING: For folders will be ignored *ALL* rules.